# How to Navigate to particular folder of Report with Navigation button in LWC

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, reporting, navigationmixin.navigate, basics

I am trying to navigate the Custom folder (Name: Account Report) of the report with the lightning button in LWC.
I am able to Navigate the home of a report by the following code. But I want to navigate to a specific folder in a report.

**HTML**

```html
<template>
    <lightning-card>
        <lightning-button label="Navigate to Report" onclick={navigateToReports}></lightning-button> 
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

**.js**

```js
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';
export default class practice extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {
    navigateToReports() {
        this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
            type: 'standard__objectPage',
            attributes: {
                objectApiName: 'Report',
                actionName: 'home'
            },
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you observe carefully for every report folder there is record id. you can use below code to navigate particular folder.

**.JS**

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';
export default class practice extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {
@track recordId='keep the wanted record ID';
    navigateToReports() {
        this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
            type: 'standard__recordPage',
            attributes: {
                recordId: this.recordId,
                objectApiName: 'Report',
               actionName:'view',
            },
        });
    }
}
```